# New Files In IIS virtual directory return file not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a virtual directory in IIS. and I added a new file to the physical directory that the virtual directory points to.

but when trying to access this file through the virtual directory - I get file not found (404).

I tried to restart the web site and the IIS Server - but it didn't help.

the file is a css file.

Comment: what is the file type? Which IIS version.. did you checked the mime type?

Answer (score 1):

There may be permissions error on accessing the file so.

> First set the permissions to full control over read /write..(Options->Security->...)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315122

Answer (score 0):

You should generally put your static files under the Content folder in an MVC application.  By default, this folder will be configured to skip the MVC routing rules.  Google for `MVC Content folder` for more information.

Comment: It is under the Content folder. but I have a few sub domains that have the same code except some images and now also the CSS file.  so we created virtual folder to all the sub domains with the same name. like this in the code we can write for all the same url. I didnt built the project, I am maintaing it. so even if it not the best way - that what i have now